# Can't install mod jk for apache

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I want to use mod_jk, i have the source, but when i run

`"./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs"`

i get this

```
no apache given
no netscape given
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
```

I installed :

- httpd-devel
- apr
- apr-devel

Comment: If you use `--with-apxs=$(which apxs2)` (or equivalent), does that improve things?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i run `native]# ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/bin/apxs` and the same problem maintain !

Comment: Did you find a method to do solve this issue?

Comment: My advice avoid source and use binary, in apache 2.4.6 if you want to use `mod_jk` enable `proxy_ajp_module` then add to your conf 
`<Location "/">
 ProxyPass ajp://ip:jk_port/
 ProxyPassReverse ajp://ip:jk_port/
</Location> `